# Multi-Step Form, Sending to Multiple Endpoints with Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a multi-step form that sends each step's data to a different endpoint, and I also want to implement validation to ensure that the user can only proceed to the next step if the data entered is valid. Finally, I want to submit all the data on the last step, but I'm not sure if I have the skills to do this.

I tried to create two classes, one for a carousel and another to submit a form, but I'm having difficulty figuring out how to implement validation to ensure that all data is validated before proceeding to the next step or submitting the entire form on the last button. Are there any tutorials or resources that can help me with this task?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a multi-step form with validation that sends data to different endpoints can be achieved with vanilla JavaScript. Here's a step-by-step guide to help you create such a form:

First, create the HTML structure for the multi-step form with a container for each step, including the input fields and navigation buttons.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Multi-Step Form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="form-container">
    <div class="step" id="step1">
      <label for="name">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" required>
      <button type="button" onclick="nextStep(2)">Next</button>
    </div>
    <div class="step" id="step2" style="display:none;">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" id="email" required>
      <button type="button" onclick="previousStep(1)">Previous</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="nextStep(3)">Next</button>
    </div>
    <div class="step" id="step3" style="display:none;">
      <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
      <input type="tel" id="phone" required>
      <button type="button" onclick="previousStep(2)">Previous</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="submitForm()">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Create a JavaScript file (script.js) to handle the form navigation and validation:

```
function showStep(stepNumber) {
  document.querySelectorAll('.step').forEach(step => {
    step.style.display = 'none';
  });
  document.getElementById(`step${stepNumber}`).style.display = 'block';
}

function nextStep(stepNumber) {
  const currentStep = stepNumber - 1;
  const inputs = document.getElementById(`step${currentStep}`).querySelectorAll('input');
  const allValid = Array.from(inputs).every(input => input.checkValidity());
  
  if (allValid) {
    sendDataToEndpoint(currentStep, inputs);
    showStep(stepNumber);
  } else {
    // Show error messages if necessary
  }
}

function previousStep(stepNumber) {
  showStep(stepNumber);
}

function sendDataToEndpoint(stepNumber, inputs) {
  const url = `https://example.com/api/step${stepNumber}`;

  const data = {};
  inputs.forEach(input => {
    data[input.id] = input.value;
  });

  fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
  });
}

function submitForm() {
  const inputs = document.getElementById('step3').querySelectorAll('input');
  const allValid = Array.from(inputs).every(input => input.checkValidity());

  if (allValid) {
    sendDataToEndpoint(3, inputs);
    // Redirect to a success page or show a success message
  } else {
    // Show error messages if necessary
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude, that was really helpful and gave me insight on what should be done to solve my problem